# Nested Interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, interface

I am trying to implement an `IFunctor` interface [Haskell's Fuctor class] and a `Maybe` interface to create two classes: `Just` and `Nothing`.

So far I have:

```
public interface IFunctor<A> {
    IFunctor<B> fmap<B> (Func<A,B> f);
}

public interface Maybe<A> : IFunctor<A> {
    Maybe<B> fmap<B> (Func<A,B> f);
}

public class Nothing<A> : Maybe<A> {

    public Maybe<B> fmap<B>( Func<A,B> f ){
        return new Nothing<B>();
    }
}
```

However I get

```
`Pr.Nothing<A>' does not implement interface member `IFunctor<A>.fmap<B>
(System.Func<A,B>)' and the best implementing candidate `Pr.Nothing<A>.fmap<B>
(System.Func<A,B>)' return type `Pr.Maybe<B>' does not match interface member return
type `IFunctor<B>'
```

Isn't `Maybe<B>` a member of `IFunctor<B>`?

**Solution**

I ended writing

```
public interface IFunctor<A> {
    IFunctor<B> fmap<B> (Func<A,B> f);
}

public interface Maybe<A> : IFunctor<A> {
    //Some stuff but not fmap
}

public class Nothing<A> : Maybe<A> {

    public IFunctor<B> fmap<B>( Func<A,B> f ){
        return new Nothing<B>();
    }
}
```

Comment: all your interface have function `fmap<B> (Func<A,B> f)` so you need implement this function in derived class for each interface, otherwise you can get error when try `(IFunctor<A>)Nothing<A>`

Answer (score 7):

`Maybe<A>.fmap()` does not `override` `IFunctor<A>.fmap()`. Any type that implements `Maybe<A>` will need to need to implement **both** `Maybe<A>` and `IFunctor<A>`.

```
public interface IFunctor<A>
{
    IFunctor<B> fmap<B>(Func<A, B> f);
}

public interface Maybe<A> : IFunctor<A>
{
    Maybe<B> fmap<B>(Func<A, B> f);
}

public class Nothing<A> : Maybe<A>
{

    public Maybe<B> fmap<B>(Func<A, B> f)
    {
        return new Nothing<B>();
    }

    //This is the explicit implementation of IFunctor<A>.fmap<B>
    //which in turn invokes method above.
    IFunctor<B> IFunctor<A>.fmap<B>(Func<A, B> f)
    {
        return this.fmap(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I where to override, because that the intention, I would override on `Maybe`?

Comment: You cannot override method definitions in a interface. An interface is a contract, and therefore a way to assume functionality about the implementer. If one _were_ to override methods it could result in undefined behaviour.